# How can a GitHub owner run and external PR through GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I got a PR at https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-store-variable/pull/58 as an external PR, hence, GitHub Actions are "restricted" for security reasons.

How can I, the owner of the destination repository, make it so that PR goes through the proper GitHub Actions without the usual restrictions?

I know I could fork the branch and make a new (internal) PR, but that takes time, is there a simpler/faster solution?

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks) what you're looking for? Or [changing this setting](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#controlling-changes-from-forks-to-workflows-in-public-repositories)?

Comment: I looked into those links, and I don't quite understand what's happening on my repo. It seems my assumption was wrong, the tests are actually running normally and were failing for a valid reason. Although, your links did help me better understand how to control that setting in the future! If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workflows, generally, by default, wont run on PRs submitted from forks from external contributors.

To allow workflows to run on such PRs, it's required to [manually approve the workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks).

> 1. Under your repository name, click **Pull requests**.
> 2. In the list of pull requests, click the pull request you'd like to review.
> 3. On the pull request, click **Files changed**.
> 4. Inspect the proposed changes in the pull request and ensure that you are comfortable running your workflows on the pull request branch. You should be especially alert to any proposed changes in the `.github/workflows/` directory that affect workflow files.
> 5. If you are comfortable with running workflows on the pull request branch, return to the **Conversation** tab, and under "Workflow(s) awaiting approval", click **Approve and run**.

It is also possible to [configure how strict or often the manual approval is required](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#controlling-changes-from-forks-to-workflows-in-public-repositories), with the three different catagories being "all workflows from all external contributors all the time", "all workflows from all external contributors the first time they are contributing here", and "all workflows from all external contributors the first time they are contributing here who are new to GitHub."

> 1. On GitHub.com, navigate to the main page of the repository.
> 2. Under your repository name, click **Settings**. If you cannot see the "Settings" tab, select the dropdown menu, then click **Settings**.
> 3. In the left sidebar, click **Actions**, then click **General**.
> 4. Under **Fork pull request workflows from outside collaborators**, choose one of the options.
> 5. Click **Save** to apply the settings.